# Is there ambiguous meaning in the sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I wrote a sentence as follows

> “the existing indexes used for different types of queries on large graphs can accelerate the speed of one type of query *they are designed for* **but not for multiple types**.”

I initially want to express that, for example, “the index A can accelerate the speed of one type of query that A is designed for, but A cannot accelerate the speed of multiple types of query”. I want to express the one-to-one relation between the existing indexes and the types of queries, not many-to-one or one-to-many relation

Here I use “**but not for multiple types**” in order to express that "existing indexes cannot accelerate the speed of multiple types of queries". But "**but not for multiple types** " can also be seen as a component of the former attributive clause, i.e. “they are designed for”. Then the whole attributive clause now is “they are designed for but not for multiple types”. In this understanding method, I think the meaning of the whole sentence is totally different from what I want to express initially.

I am not sure that is there ambiguous meaning that cannot convey my initial meaning because "but not for multiple types" can be seen as a component of the former attributive clause?

Comment: Note that the usual plural of index is **indices**. Both are used however as shown in this [Google nGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=indexes%2Cindices&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cindexes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cindices%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cindexes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cindices%3B%2Cc0)  - Many scientists don't have a good grasp of language!

Comment: Ignore the above comment and read this for well-referenced factual discussion: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61080/the-plural-of-index-indexes-or-indices

Answer (score 1):

> “the existing indexes used for different types of queries on large
> graphs can accelerate the speed of one type of query they are designed
> for but not for multiple types.”

This doesn't make sense to me. I think you mean

*Existing indexes used for queries on large graphs can accelerate the speed of the specific type of query they are designed for but are ineffective for multiple types.*

---

In response to comment

*Existing indexes used for queries on large graphs can accelerate the speed only of the specific type of query they are designed for and are ineffective for other types.*

Comment: Yes, I think your sentence can convey my meaning better! One index is only effective for one type of query, but it cannot work for other types of queries. May I ask that can I remove "different types of " in "used for different types of queries" like your sentence? Because I want to express the one-to-one relation between the existing indexes and the types of queries, not many-to-one or one-to-many relation, I afraid that if I remove "different types of ", there may be some other ambiguous meaning.

Comment: I've added another suggestion.

Comment: I think the new sentence is better.Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually I think "other" would be better than "different". I'll make that change.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you.